# Selenium click on a button opens a new tab when manual click doesn't

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I encountered weird bug.

**When** I click on a button *using selenium webdriver* **then** a page that is supposed to be loaded opens in a new tab.

**When** I click on the button *manually* **then** no new tab opens (it's is what supposed to be made).

**It happens with ChromeDriver**, doesn't happen with Firefox driver.

The button I click on is located using CSS Selector and it is located correctly (as in FireFox it works, also I checked it using search by selector in the code of the page).

**Here is a video of how it's going on:** http://screencast.com/t/SgSZneYwHstR

**ChromeDriver:** 2.21.0.0

**Webdriver**: 2.53.0

**Language:** C#

Do you guys have any suggestions of how to fix it or why it happens?

Comment: Post the html;.  Hypothesis is that chromedriver thinks it is visible and firefox thinks it is hidden